# Save a variable and use it in later stage in Ramda compose

Tags: javascript, node.js, ramda.js

I am very new to Ramda and have got stuck in a problem. I need to get response from an api and pass it to next function but that same response needs to be used again at a later stage in the same compose. How can I save its value in that ramda func scope so it can be re-used again?

```
const getData = (req, ctx) => R.compose
        (
          R.andThen(... do some action using response from callSomeApi_2 and prop2)
        , callSomeApi_2(req, ctx)
        , R.andThen(R.map(R.prop('prop1'))) // response has prop1 and prop2 where prop2 is needed after getting response from callSomeApi_2
        , callSomeApi_1(req, ctx)
        );
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use `R.props()` instead of `R.prop()`
so the code becomes something like that :

```
const getData = (req, ctx) => R.compose
    (
      R.andThen(... do some action using response from callSomeApi_2 and prop2)
    , callSomeApi_2(req, ctx)
    , R.andThen(R.map(R.props('prop1', 'prop2'))) // this will include both properties 1 & 2
    , callSomeApi_1(req, ctx)
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer!